# is there a way to pre sign tx with metamask?

Tags: metamask

so, i was just to know if there is a way to sign transaction with metamask. What im trying to do is to actually just sign a transaction with the metamask to be broadcasted later, but metamask seems to not support signing transactions. So i just would like to know if thats possible to do or not.

Comment: A longer thread on metamask repos about the issue of signing transaction without sending them https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/3475.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no. It's not possible by just using Metamask, but it's possible by constructing a raw transaction in a website and asking Metamask to sign that.

This actually happens in almost the same way as signing messages; you simply sign a transaction instead of a message. Here's how you'd do it with ethers.js: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signTransaction